# How can I do join with whereDoesntHave in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to run a query in my `Laravel 8.0` application. I've a problem doing join (circular) using the concept of `whereDoesntHave()` in `Laravel`. Since I'm using `DB::table('...')` and it has other conditions implemented, I'm having a `brands` table, `projects` table and `project_associate_brand` table, `brand` is in `many-to-many` relation with `project`, I want to find out the project counts in which brand and projects are not associated with each other, I'm trying to join the table twice one for getting projects associated with and other one to remove where it is not in relationship, so my query looks like:

```
$innerQuery = DB::table('brands as b')
    ->join('project_associate_brand as  pabdoesnthave', 'b.id', '=', 'pabdoesnthave.brand_id')
    ->join('project_associate_brand as pab', function ($join) {
        $join->on('b.id', '!=', 'pab.brand_id')
            ->where('pabdoesnthave.project_id', '!=', 'pab.project_id');
    })
    ->join('projects as p', function ($join) {
        $join->on('pab.project_id', '=', 'p.id')
           ->where('pabdoesnthave.project_id', '!=', 'p.id');
    })
     ->select(DB::raw('b.id, b.title, COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) as projects_count'))
    ->whereNull('b.deleted_at')
    ->whereNull('p.deleted_at')
    ->groupByRaw('b.id');
    
    
return ProductBrandFilterResource::collection(DB::query()->fromSub($innerQuery, 't')
    ->select(DB::raw("
                id,
                `title`,
                projects_count
         "))
    ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('t.id')->get());
```

I'm unable get the desired results. To explain better I've table `porject_associate_brand` as:

```
brand_id    project_id
    1           1
    1           2
    1           3
    2           1
    2           3
```

If I want to get the list of brand where projects are not associated I get

```
id  title   project_count
1   ABC         3
2   PQR         3
```

For id 2 it is giving me 3 but actually it should be 1 as result.

Any better approach is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `whereDoesntHave` requires using eloquent and relationships but here you are using `DB` and joins.

Comment: Can you explain why brand id 2 should have a count of 1 ?